# Package does not exist IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ to develop a java application but I'm not able to import any of the packages I created. I marked my **src folder** as Sources Root and the tree suggests I'm able to import a package by just

```
import service.RMI;
```

on my App.java file.

but when I try to compile

```
javac App.java
```

I get an error saying

```
App.java:4: error: package service does not exist
import service.RMI;
              ^
```

Does anyone knows why this happens? Does it have to do with my project skeleton?

For a better understanding, I leave my project tree:

```
.
├── algorithms
│   └── SHA256.java
├── app
│   ├── App.class
│   └── App.java
├── file
│   ├── ChunkFile.java
│   └── Chunk.java
├── filesystem
│   └── filesystem.java
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── peer
│   ├── listeners
│   │   ├── MClistener.java
│   │   └── MDBlistener.java
│   └── Peer.java
├── protocols
│   ├── Backup.java
│   ├── Delete.java
│   └── Restore.java
└── service
    └── RMI.java
```

Comment: Can you try rebuilding your project?

Comment: Refresh, Rebuild, Restart.  In that order, see if it works :)

Comment: Is `.` the Source root?

Comment: I builded the project but I get the same error when doing `javac App.java`

Comment: It is @CrazyCoder . My src folder

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
I was compiling all wrong. I was trying to run

```
javac App.java
```

on my app directory but I figured out that I need to run

```
javac app/App.java
```

on my root directory - src, and then, to run the app I need

```
java app.App
```

Thanks for the kind replies.

Regards